# Laptop won't boot after running executable in wrong location

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot

I wanted to make a bootable flash drive to try out Porteus Linux. I made the stupid mistake of running an .exe file that comes with Porteus (should be run from the flash drive of course) and makes the USB stick bootable from my Windows 7 desktop (desktop as in location /desktop).

Now I can't boot back into Windows 7 and I get an error `Syslinux: No default or configuration directive found and an option to type under boot`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It has changed the default bootloader of your drive. You must [recover windows 7 boot loader](http://superuser.com/questions/282720/reinstalling-windows-7-bootloader).

Answer (score 0):

You somehow installed the Syslinux bootloader.
You can try to boot from a Windows installation disc and try repairing the System.